# Why is clear interval speeding up rotation after hover out

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I have a rotating slider on a website that I am working on.

the slider automatically scrolls when the page is loaded, and is supposed to stop when it is moused over, and then start again when the mouse leaves.

I have the stopping of the slider working, but when i mouse out, the slider starts up again, but twice as fast, causing the slider to show no content.

Is there some reason why my clear interval is not working correctly? how can i get the slider to stop and start without it changing speed and messing up?

```
     rotateSwitch: function() {  
       var myTimer=setInterval(function() { this.autoRotate(); }.bind(this), 5000);
       $('.hero img').hover(
         function() {
         window.clearInterval(myTimer)},
         function() {
         this.rotateSwitch();}.bind(this));
    },
```

Comment: Every time `rotateSwitch` is called, the event is bound again.  So the `mouseout` event is running twice, thus registering the interval twice.  Or, at least, that's what I think may be going on.

Comment: That makes sense to me. I'm just not sure how to correct it.

Comment: Maybe you can bind the event outside of the function?

Comment: Any idea on how that would be written?

Comment: What is the object that this method is part of?  Is there a "constructor"?

Comment: Here is more of the code, added above

Comment: Try to put the `$('.hero img').hover(` inside `init`.  You'll also need to change `var myTimer` to `this.myTimer`.

Comment: hmm, that did'nt seem to do anything. My stop on hover stopped working also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every mouseleave you bind the function again by calling `this.rotateSwitch()`. Instead, only start the interval again:

```
rotateSwitch: function() {  
    var myTimer,
        that = this;
    function start() {
        myTimer = setInterval(that.autoRotate.bind(that), 5000);
    }
    function stop() {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
    $('.hero img').hover(stop, start);
    start();
},
```

If that function is called multiple times, you might want to restrict your `.hero img` selector to a specific context as well.